# php - one form, multiple submits with onclick event

Tags: submit, form-submit

I have a form with two submit buttons, in code behind I got the values from each submit, but the problem is when I add a javascript onclick event on each submit, when I try to retrieve the values in PHP I get nothing. I get the input submit values only when I don't use an event.

I don't get the input submit values from this code:

```
<input type="submit" id="send1" value="Send1" name="sub1" onclick="validate1();"/>
<input type="submit" id="send2" value="Send2" name="sub2" onclick="return validate2();"/>
```

This one works:

```
<input type="submit" id="send1" value="Send1" name="sub1" />
<input type="submit" id="send2" value="Send2" name="sub2" />
```

Comment: can you also include your javascript code as well

Comment: Please show JavaScript code. Check the output of JavaScript console.

Comment: Is very simple. The validate1 just disable the submit button and change the button's label. The validate2 is checking if any of my fields are empty and disable the submit button too.

Comment: Find the error. If I disable the input button, I don't get any value, otherwise is ok. Trying to find out a solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. If a value of a disabled button cannot be posted, then I'm just adding a hidden field with some value identifying the submit button clicked.

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_post_value" name="my_post_value"/>
```

Comment: That was the solution I posted above, you should, at least, give credit! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick setup to do what you want
https://jsfiddle.net/d090618g/

**Your HTML**

```
 <form id="theform">

    <input type="submit" name="s1" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="s2" />

    <input type="hidden" name="clicked" id="clicked" />

</form>    

<div id="result"></div>
```

**Quick JQuery**

```
var $form    = $("#theform");
var $clicked = $("#clicked");

$form.find( "input[type='submit']").click( function(){
    $clicked.val( $(this).attr('name') );
});

$form.submit( function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    switch( $clicked.val() ){

        case 's1':
            alert( "Do thing 1" );
            return;

        case 's2':
            alert( "Do thing 2" );
            return;
    }

    //post your form to PHP here        

    $("#result").html( $clicked.val() );

});
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and what is your solution?